# Maximum value of a function whose sum of roots is known

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, factoring

I have a set of unequal positive integers $X_1,X_2,X_3,X_4,....,X_n$ whose sum is known.
How do I find the maximum value of $(X_1^2-X_1)(X_2^2-X_1)(X_3^2-X_3)....(X_N^2-X_N)$?

Comment: What is the pattern?

Comment: I am sorry, I don't understand what you mean by "pattern"

Comment: I know. But I wanted to know if there's a way to find its maximum value.

Comment: So, do you think that in a particular range, it is safe to say that the maximum value for the expression is attained when the product of $x_1,x_2...$ is the highest?

Comment: @Jens.  No, the numbers are positive.

Comment: @William They are now. They weren't when I made that comment.